# MS-Access form, want text to wrap without truncation (as in reports)

Tags: ms-access-2007, reporting

I have a form that shows a list. One of the fields is of type text, with max. length of 255. This field appears truncated on the form. The `Can Grow` property is set to `'Yes'`.

I want the height to be dynamically adjusted in each row based on the number of characters in the current filed. This happens in reports but not in form fields in this case.

I tried to compare the properties in the form with the report but could not spot a difference.

How can I do that please? Thx.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>No chance (scnr),</s>  This property doesn't work in form view, only if the form is printed.

[TextBox.CanGrow Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194664.aspx)

> This property affects the display of form sections and controls only when the form is printed or previewed, not when the form is displayed in Form view, Datasheet view, or Design view.

**Edit**

You can take a look at http://lebans.com/cangrow.htm

Stephen Lebans is an API wizard, you will find lots of complicated code in there, but it may do what you want. But you'll have to decide if it's worth the additional code and potential instabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is hard to sell such a form to users who are used to using MS-Excel. They think it is the programmer's mistake.

Comment: One possibility, if you have a continuous form with many small fields and one large field, is to move the large field into the form footer. So only the description of the *current record* is shown there. Optionally have a small, locked, field in the detail section as a "preview". @NoChance

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it out.